# Setting UIViews layer.cornerRadius adds gray lines around the view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, layer, cornerradius

Both background and border color are set to white, there is no gray color in my code anywhere.
But when I set views cornerRadius I see two gray lines left and right from the view(sometimes up and down too, depending on the UIViews function)
Although when I set views backgroundColor to clear, lines disappear. Any reason for this to happen?

EDIT:

This only happens on iphone device, not on simulator, dont know why :/
Here I have one big white UView and 8 smaler ones inside it, and I am using constrains for the autolayout(but no problem there), and when I set all of these small views background color to clear, they disapear(also this big white view is responsible for the few of these gray lines)

And solution to the problem is either removing cornerRadius or seting background color to clear.
[image]

Comment: Take a picture and add here.

Comment: there it is with few extra comments

Comment: is this dynamically done or interface builder? also can you help me identify where the 8 views are on this image (if interface, can you screen shot, if code, can you attach code)

Comment: its code, but what part do you want me to attach, constraints or view implementations, there are 4 on left and 4 on right, just between these vertical gray line